# Wake up background app by itself

Tags: ios, background

Let say "My app(BLE related) is on background mode. Also, it is still connected to BLE on background".
I want to wake up this app for foreground as soon as getting any value from BLE network.
Is it possible? If yes, which method can be available?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not bring any app to foreground programmatically. But you can show an alert to launch the app.